# Xamarin Forms Tap Gesture Click Effect on Stack layout

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, c#-4.0

Please i will like to know how to achieve a click effect on a stacklayout. I have my design, i use stacklayout and tap gesture to navigate to other pages. However, when i click it feels static and i need to see a click effect.

Below is my design [image]

I want the effect to show when i click any of these options (falut, outage etc) just like when i click on a button control.

Thanks

Comment: Like a ripple? Or a click Scale effect.

Comment: Any of both. I just want to show that the stack was clicked

Comment: try adding behavior to it

Comment: How do u add behavior? Can u direct me to an example?

Comment: Can you add the XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions which can implement it . For example ,you could set the `BackgroundColor` of the StackLayout in tap directly .

```
private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var stack = sender as StackLayout;

            stack.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;

            await Task.Delay(100); // delay 0.1s

            stack.BackgroundColor = Color.LightBlue; // set it to the default color that you define in xaml

            //do something you want
        }
```

### Solution 2

You could use the plugin [XamEffects](https://github.com/mrxten/XamEffects) from nuget .

#### Usage

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamEffects.Sample"
             xmlns:xe="clr-namespace:XamEffects;assembly=XamEffects"
             x:Class="xxx.MainPage">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"
          VerticalOptions="Center"
          HeightRequest="100"
          WidthRequest="200"
          xe:TouchEffect.Color="Red">
       
         //put content of StackLayout  here
    </StackLayout >
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thank You.. I have implemented using the Solution 2. The effect shows up well. However, the action of taking me to the next page. What could be the issue?

Comment: You could create a new thread with more details so that I can help you better .